# how do I set permalink for octopress 3

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I have tried to set permalinks without dates in octopress 3.

I set it with the _config.yml.

`permalink: :title/`

But it only generates url's with .html

How do I create real permalinks in octopress 3?

Answer (score 0):

It works, I hadn't included the `/` originally.